# angular Fullcalendar does not refresh in IE 11

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

We have a button to refresh,and on refresh we have to clear the eventSources array and fill it with new data.
This is the original events array.

```
this.calEvents = [
    { title: 'All Day Event', start: new Date(y, m, 1) },
    { title: 'Long Event', start: new Date(y, m, d - 5), end: new Date(y, m, d - 2) },
    { id: 999, title: 'Repeating Event', start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0), allDay: false },
    { id: 999, title: 'Repeating Event', start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0), allDay: false },
    { title: 'Birthday Party', start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0), end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30), allDay: false },
    { title: 'Click for Google', start: new Date(y, m, 28), end: new Date(y, m, 29), url: 'http://google.com/' }
];
this.eventSources = [this.calEvents];
```

The is the code to refresh fullcalendar on button click,

```
var eventSources = this.calEvents.map((event) => {
    return {
        title: event.title,
        start: event.start
    }
});
this.uiCalendarConfig.calendars['myCalendar'].fullCalendar('removeEvents') 
this.uiCalendarConfig.calendars['myCalendar'].fullCalendar('addEventSource', eventSources);
this.uiCalendarConfig.calendars['myCalendar'].fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

The above code works in Chrome but does not work in IE 11.

Is there a seperate API to refresh data in IE ?

This is the eventSources array.
[image: eventsources Array]
Thanks!

Comment: Any errors thrown in the console?  What does your events function look like (the one that `refetchEvents` triggers)?

Comment: no errors in IE console. I added the eventSources array image. The same array works in chrome.

Comment: I noticed if i click anywhere in the page it renders. I tried adding a $timeout, but no luck.